# Crawling error in Scrapy using LinkExtractor and Rule

Tags: python, regex, parsing, web-scraping, scrapy

I have written a simple crawler in Scrapy 1.5 in Python3 and I am scraping the posts and its contents in it.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class DailyStrengthSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'daily_strength'
    allowed_domains = ['dailystrength.org']
    start_urls = ['https://www.dailystrength.org/search?query=avastin/']
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths = '//*[@class="newsfeed__title-block"]/h2/a/@href'),follow = True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow = r'/group/[a-zA-z]\-/discussion/[a-zA-z0-9]\_\-',callback = 'parse_post'))
    )
```

Here I am specifying the URLs to be allowed in the above line. I got an error  saying

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'callback'

I've verified the syntax in tutorials.

```
def parse_post(self,response):
    user = response.xpath('//*[@class="newsfeed__posted-by"]/a/text()').extract_first()
    time = response.xpath('//*[@class="newsfeed__item-time"]/text()').extract_first()
    full_post = response.xpath('//*[@class="posts__content"]/text()').extract_first()
    comment_users = response.xpath('//*[@class="comments__name"]/a/text()').extract()
    comments = response.xpath('//*[@class="comments__comment-text"]/text()').extract() 
    yield {"UserName":user,"Time":time,"Post":full_post}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the `callback` argument to the `LinkExtractor` instead of passing it to the `Rule` object.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class DailyStrengthSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'daily_strength'
    allowed_domains = ['dailystrength.org']
    start_urls = ['https://www.dailystrength.org/search?query=avastin/']
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths = '//*[@class="newsfeed__title-block"]/h2/a/@href'),follow = True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow = r'/group/[a-zA-z]\-/discussion/[a-zA-z0-9]\_\-'), callback = 'parse_post')
    )
```

Comment: I am getting an error **AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iter'** and also an **ERROR: Spider error processing** in the debug window @VMRuiz

Comment: @Vignesh I miss a comma before the `callback` param. See if that solves it.

Comment: I did not understand the use of LinkExtractor function still and it has not crawled the webpages specified in the **start_urls** and how can I find the pages that are **being crawled** by the LinkExtractor function @VMRuiz

Comment: @Vignesh, If you turn on the logs in Debug Mode (as it is by default) you will see the URLs that are being crawled.

Comment: **INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)** it hasn't crawled the pages other than the home page. I don't where the error is. Maybe is it in the **allowed_urls** ?

Comment: Are you sure that your regular expresion are correct and able to find links? Also, are you sure that the webpage is not redender using javascript (in that case, scrapy won't find anything because it doesn't run javascript code)

Answer (score 0):

You pass `callback` to `LinkExtractor` constructor (which [does not accept this parameter](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#module-scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml)), though it is intended to go to `Rule` constructor.

Just change the constructor invocation:

```
Rule(LinkExtractor(allow = r'/group/[a-zA-z]\-/discussion/[a-zA-z0-9]\_\-'), callback = 'parse_post')
```